# Asymmetric simple random walk?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

[image]

It comes from the book Probability: Theory and Example.
**I don't understand the part marked with red line.
Why it cannot converge to an interior point of $(a,b)$?**

Can anyone help? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the random walk has $+-1$ valued steps, converging to  an interior point means that the walker has to remain at that point for every step after a certain time, which is impossible.